# Html Js For loop with spottily play buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to make a for loop that displays the spotify play button for every URI I put in a specific list. So if this album "spotify:album:08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth" was in the list it would display as

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

So the for loop would put the uri in the `<iframe>` tag.

Here is the following code i have, I have already looked at many tutorials and examples online but can't figure it out for this type of situation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var list = ["spotify:album:08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  text += <iframe src=" cars[i]" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe> + "<br>";

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very close - you need to select the `08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth` from your array list, and make the `<iframe>` an actual element. You should also use `appendChild()` not `innerHTML`:

```
var list = ["spotify:album:08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth"];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var source = list[i].split(":")[2];
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = source;
    iframe.width = "300";
    iframe.height = "380";
    iframe.frameborder = "0";
    iframe.allowtransparency = "true";
    iframe.allow = "encrypted-media";
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: then how exactly would you get it to display? I felt it would be by doing such: <p id="demo"></p>, as that would then take all info in the for loop and display it?

Comment: What do you mean? The `<iframe>` is a child of the `<p id="demo">` element - so it should display perfectly fine.

Comment: I've been trying something like this,but dont get the play button of album